# Development methods C# and SQL Database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I've been googeling and testing this issue now for a while. Here is my question:

We develop in Visual Studio 2010 the C# part and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for the Views/Stored Procedures/... part.

What I want to do is combine both systems so that:

- The developer writes the C# code in the C# project
- The developer writes the stored procedure in the SQL project

  - He can test the stored procedure against the test environment database from VS
- When he wants to test the C# code, the stored procedure is beeing created runtime ONLY. When The application stops (break) the object is beeing destroyed.

Maybe you can help me.

Comment: Have you considered Entity Framework Code First as an option?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a Visual Studio database project (instead of SQL Server Management Studio) and you want the developer to work against a local development database when debugging (which he should be doing anyway).  In the latter case, if the database project is set to deploy to the database as part of running the project then it would update the stored procedure(s) (and other database objects) when the solution is built/deployed as part of invoking the debugger.

Comment: Look at CLR Object in SQL Server. I've never done it, though

Comment: @websch01ar: Entity Framework Code First looks very promising but, unfortunately can not be used in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 you may need to install the sql server data tools (used to create database projects).  It's installed with VS 2012 but I'm not sure about VS2010.

Here are some links for more information:
Site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx
Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/

Comment: For Visual Studio 2010 you can download SSDT from the links you posted. It also supports database unit testing and using local/test databases during development so it definitely sounds like it would meet Jeppen's needs.